# Swift Codable Map Children by ID

Tags: swift, codable

I have the following code.

```
import Foundation

let jsonData = """
[
    {"id": "1", "firstname": "Tom", "lastname": "Smith", "age": "28"},
    {"id": "2", "firstname": "Bob", "lastname": "Smith"},
    {"id": "3", "firstname": "Jim", "lastname": "Smith", "parentid": "2"},
    {"id": "4", "firstname": "Ray", "lastname": "Smith", "parentid": "3"}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!

class Person: Codable {
    let id: String
    let firstName, lastName: String
    let age: String?
    let parentid: String?
    let children: [Person]?

    enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "firstname"
        case lastName = "lastname"
        case age
        case parentid
        case id
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
        lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)
        age = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .age)
        parentid = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .parentid)
        id = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id)
    }

}

let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: jsonData)
print(decoded)
```

So I have that `children` property. I basically want `decoded` to be an array with 2 `Person` objects (Tom and Bob). `decoded[1].children` should be an array with 1 `Person` object (Jim). And `decoded[1].children[0]` should be an array with 1 `Person` object (Ray).

How can I achieve this using the Swift Codable system?

Comment: lol. You are funny.  My answer is so huge to write its body in the comments

Comment: Not every question has got a solution

Comment: @Vyacheslav You know that’s not true. You can do anything in coding. Might require thinking about the problem differently. But I have NEVER seen a case where given an input it’s impossible to get an expected output.

Comment: Ok. If iit is possible It would be nice if somebody (maybe you) answered your question

Comment: @Vyacheslav Maybe there is a reason I asked it? If I could answer it myself why would I ask it? I'm currently playing around trying to get it to work outside of the Codable system. Sorting the output array and moving the elements around and such. Part of coding is problem solving. There is always problems you have to solve. I'm shocked that you don't realize this and are willing to give up so quickly. If you want to give up that quickly then no need for you to answer the question or comment.

Comment: @Vyacheslav look at the answer provided. Next time don't dismiss questions as not having a solution. Part of coding is problem solving. If you aren't willing to solve problems you are in the wrong industry.

Comment: my dear friend. You asked namely "How can I achieve this using the Swift **Codable system**?" . This answer you approved is not using Codable system. This is not you are looking for.  I said that there is no solution that uses decoding. This is just a simple loop **after** decoding. lol. Have a nice day;)

Comment: @Vyacheslav As I said before. “Might require thinking about the problem differently”. I stand correct. I have NEVER seen a case where given an input it’s impossible to get an expected output. All I’m saying is sometimes providing different and creative solutions on Stack Overflow is a great idea and something you should embrace instead of just dismissing questions.

Comment: nonetheless, you asked about another solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
    if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: jsonData)
    {
        for person in decoded
        {
            person.children = decoded.filter({ (child) -> Bool in
                return person.id == child.parentid
            })
        }
    }
```

In the above code, after getting `decoded` array I just traversed it using a `for loop` to identify the `children` of each `person` if exist.

Comment: Awesome. Then how would I get the final array?

Comment: Decoded is the final array you’ll get after executing for loop. Just print decoded after the for loop is finished.

Comment: Ok so it might be best to create a separate variable beforehand to store the final result in. Thanks!

Comment: Sure..happy coding 